# .xls Excel File With Protected Fields Allow Editing in 2007, Not 2010 or 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

We have a form in use at the office. This form is a .xls file. Most cells are protected with the exception of data entry cells. I am able to edit at will in Excel 2007, however in 2010 and 2013, *any* attempt at entering data results in Excel popping a password dialog. I also used 2013's convert document feature (to get out of compatibility mode), and that didn't work either. Has anyone else seen this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Can you unprotect the 2007 file completely, open it in 2010, then re-protect it?